# Request does not match any route, when try save order in cron job

Tags: orders, crontab

I have a problem when trying to modify an order through a cronjob this code works perfectly, but when executing it inside the cronjob it indicates that error "Request does not match any route"

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    class cronTest
    {
        public function __construct(
        ) {
            
        }
        public function execute()
        {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderId = 8;
            $order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

if I use this same code in an observer for example, it works without any problem

My crontab.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\cronTest" method="execute" name="testCronJob">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule> 
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

---

I have found a temporary solution, create an api and consume it from the cronjob to get the desired behavior

Comment: please share your crontab.xml file code

Comment: hello friend there share the crontab.xml, thank you very much for any help you can give me

Comment: what you want to change in order please let me know.

Comment: my end goal is to change the price and quantity of the products, but suppose I need to change the order status.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code below

> **app\code\Vendor\CronTest\Cron\CronTest.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\CronTest\Cron;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
class CronTest
{

protected $logger;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 * Execute the cron
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/crontest.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $this->logger->addInfo("Cronjob CronTest is executed.");
    try {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orderId = 25;
        $order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
        $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $order->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->addInfo($e->getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

> **app/code/Vendor/CronTest/etc/crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job instance="Vendor\CronTest\Cron\CronTest" method="execute" name="vendor_crontest_crontest">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Use below cmd to execute cron job

> **sudo php bin/magento cron:run --group="default"**

Please check below screen shot of order status
Before Cron job
[image]

**

> **After Cron job**

**

[image]

Comment: I tried to run the code, but the same problem keeps happening                                       [2020-08-23 18:10:03] main.INFO: Cronjob CronTest is executed. [] []
[2020-08-23 18:10:03] main.INFO: Request does not match any route. [] []

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Request does not match any route. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Exception(code: 0): Request does not match any route. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/Router.php:57)"} []